# Brake Pedal/M. Cylinder Squeaks And Can’t Bleed

Tags: brakes, chrysler, fluid, sebring

I have an ‘02 Chrysler Sebring that I’ve been working on as a project. When I got it, it had front brakes but the calipers in the rear were so gone they wouldn’t work.

I have since bought new calipers, rotors, and pads all around. 
While trying to bleed them, I noticed no fluid was coming out. I checked the fluid in the resovior and there was so little left, so I filled it up. I attempted the bleed again and still nothing came out. The lines are empty.

Then I thought, maybe it’s the master cylinder that needs bleeding. I was coming to do it when I noticed that the brakes squeak when being pressed. I’ve attached a video.

https://streamable.com/binyv

Comment: No need to bleed the master cylinder, just buy a bleeding tool to help with it since lines are empty.

Comment: I ended up buying a bleeding tool, and nothing was coming out of the caliper. Just pure air. I disconnected my hard line to see if anything was coming through, and sure enough it was. However, the bleeder valve on the caliper just spits pure air. I'm baffled.

Comment: You will get some air as it leaks past the threads on the bleeder., but some fluid also, only open the bleeder a 1/4 turn from closed.

Comment: That’s what’s supposed to happen, however I’m getting nothing but air out of my bleeder valve, despite the fact the hardline has fluid going through. They’re brand new calipers. Should I have bench bled them before installing them?

Comment: Then the bleeder hole down in the caliper is blocked, pull the bleeder screw all the way out and poke a small metal pick down in the hole to unclog it.